# Android image that can support both 5.4" FWVGA mdpi and 3.2" QVGA mdpi?

Tags: android, android-drawable, mdpi

I know that you have to put images for medium density devices in `drawable-mdpi` folder. But the image that look perfect for `3.2" mdpi` devices looks small for `5.4" mdpi` device. How can I resolve this.